# Detox: How to Provide bitrise build path to Detox configurations to test E2E on bitrise

Tags: build, path, detox, bitrise

In order to improve build times we plan to use bitrise builds to test e2e with detox.

I found that we can provide device name at run time with **--device-name** 
 i.e **detox test -c android.emu.release --device-name Nexus 5X**, but I could not find any flag to provide **buildPath**

Is it possible to provide the same in any manner?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to configure detox at run time by modifying the init.js file in e2e folder as below

```
import { BUILD_PATH } from 'react-native-dotenv';

const detox = require('detox');
const adapter = require('detox/runners/jest/adapter');

const config = require('../package.json').detox;

jest.setTimeout(120000);
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(adapter); // eslint-disable-line

beforeAll(async () => {
  config.configurations['ios.sim.cli'].binaryPath = BUILD_PATH;
  await detox.init(config);
});
```